# Why i cannot assign an aritmetic expression for my variable value in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm new at programming stuff and i'm practicing with variables, so i made a code in C++ where basically i do something like this:

```
float a;

a=4/3;

printf("%f", a);
return 0;
```

i expected to get the result as 1.333, but instead i got 1 as value

But if i do this:

```
float a, b=4, c=3;

a=b/c;

printf("%f", a);
return 0;
```

It gives back the right value (1.3333)

can somenone please explain that to me?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, C++ being less than helpful. This is going to annoy you.

```
  4 / 3
```

This is INTEGER math, not floating point. This would work if you did one of these:

```
  4.0 / 3
  4 / 3.0
  4.0 / 3.0
```

C++ won't upscale your values to floating point while doing the calculation unless there are floating point values somewhere in the calculation itself.